# Increase the download speed of a large number of variations in WooCommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Hello everyone from Russia. I have 2700 product variations. When I change "woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold" to 2700, the product page is loaded for 1 minute.
How to speed up this time?
Or, for example, when opening a product, load 30 variations, and when the product page opens, the other variations will be loaded in the background. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The mistake is setting `woocommerce_ajax_variation_threshold` to a high number, because then all variations are loaded via ajax. Which takes time, especially with that many variations. If you're over the threshold, all combinations should be can be selected, this is instead of being filter beforehand via ajax. Availability now is checked after selecting the variations by their conditions, either resulting in a price shown or a not available message.

Comment: Thank. I understand what you mean. But I want, that the non-existent variations are not displayed, it frightens the buyer. How else can this be realized?
Спасибо.  Я понимаю, что вы имеете ввиду. Но я хочу, что бы несуществующие вариации не отображались, это отпугивает покупателя.  Как ещё можно этого реализовать?

Comment: Hello. In the search for an answer, I met these words: "instead of pulling lists out of the database, give the generated text (via ajax pull a static, pre-prepared file)" can this help? I can make such a file, but can I really connect it?